# R error in loading packages "ape" and "Rcpp"

Tags: r, package, loading

the packages "ape" and "Rcpp" install on my Mac(latest version) fine, its just whenever I load them the same error comes up for both:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
```

I have tried reinstalling both packs, updating and reinstalling R too.
Im very new to R so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, sorry, I don't have OSX, but do you have all the build tools you need for R [OSX build tools](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a long time today trying to figure this out. When nothing else worked, I updated my RStudio (which did not help either). However, after that, I update my R version and that fixed the issue for me.