# Some Packages Fail to Load

Tags: r, package

Tidyverse and several other packages fail to load when I try both library(package) and selecting the checkbox for the package.

The same error message (below) results for all such cases. This is really strange because everything worked just fine the day before yesterday. I've tried restarting everything without success.

Please give any suggestions if you think you know whats going on. Thanks

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
```

Comment: Have you installed the Rccp package?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991230/r-error-in-loading-packages-ape-and-rcpp

Answer (score 0):

I decided to uninstall and reinstall v4 and everything works fine now.